# removing side space between para and container on generatepress?

Tags: themes, css, html

There’s space between paragraphs and container when I open my website on a mobile device only. I want to reduce that space, how can I do that on generatepress theme on WordPress. this is the space I’m talking about: https://prnt.sc/10zlb9p URL=https://priceunder.in/dolby-digital-vs-dts-x/

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the "Inspect Tool" in your browser to see the details of the object (structure and style). Though I checked your page and didn't see anything wrong with it. As you can see in the list in the top of your picture, the last item has a few space.

Another point is in the beginning of the line, all words start in the same place and the left padding would be OK. But since all the words does not have the same length and they can be half-written in the end of the line, so the long words may be placed on the next line. This way some lines might be shorter and some lines might be longer and you think that there's something wrong with the space ( As you can see in the "Power" paragraph and the last 3 lines ).